# jquery: how to set class members' widths to those of their respective parents?

Tags: jquery

Say .item members are contained inside several elements of different widths. I want every .item to have the width of the element it's contained in... I don't know how to do that.

```
$(".item").width(???);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the [function callback signature of `.width`](http://api.jquery.com/width/):

```
$('.item').width(function() {
    return $(this).parent().width();
});
```

Comment: thanks, I was doing it right then, it's a problem with my css, it has zero width only in MSIE7.